# Excel find max with text

Tags: excel

My question is the next. There are 2 columns. 
D an E.

What im trying to do is to find the duplicate numbers in column D and find the maximum number of them in E.

The problem is that there should be three results:

1: if the cells are blanks than the result should be blank.
2: if the cells have blanks and n or just n than the result should be n.
3: if the cells are numbers as well than the result should be the max number

i have tried the MAX function with IF but it comes back with "0" result in both empty an n cells as well. I know that the max has numeric returns so my question is that is there any way to achieve to get the results without using script?

[image]

The result (max:) here should be "n";

if finds=3 than results (max:) should be the max number;

if finds=2 than the result (max:) should be blank

Thanks for any ideas!!

Comment: Sounds like you need some sort of index match rather than max, although it really isn't very clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula

```
=IF(MAX(IF(B1=D2:D13,ISNUMBER(E2:E13)*1)),MAX(IF(D2:D13=B1,IF(ISNUMBER(E2:E13),E2:E13))),IF(MAX(IF(B1=D2:D13,(E2:E13="n")*1)),"n",""))
```

confirmed with ctrl+shift+enter gives

```
1 -> 20
2 -> ""
3 -> 80
4 -> "n"
5 -> #N/A
```

The idea is that numbers have priority over everything and "n" has priority over "". Therefore the formula checks if any numbers exist, if the do, the max from them is taken. If no numbers exist, a check for "n" is performed and depending of the results "n" or "" is returned.

Comment: Hi. This is exactly what i needed! Thank you for your help!! I have tried ISNUMBER as well but not like this and now i can see where I did mistake. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As `MAXA` actually considers text and booleans the result is actually correct. The only value that your `IF` returns is `n` and a lot of `FALSE`'s that numerically are equal to 0 (only `D$12$` fulfills the condition =4, so returns value of `E$12$`). If you put a numerical value in `E$13$`, that number shows as the result. Regards,